# Значение <<< в PHP

Tags: php

Что означают такие загадочные три <<< перед переменными?
Например:
    $message = <<<ENDMSG
            Thank you for signing up at our site.  Please go to
    $url to activate your account.
    ENDMSG;
    mail($address, "Activate your account", $message);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEREDOC. Непосредственное присвоение указанного значения. Самый быстрый способ, но читаемость роняется до 0, имхо.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc-синтаксис